# How can you display full traceback on phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For example, when there is a KeyError on a very big map it wont display all the map and remain truncated, so it wont display the line where the traceback is appearing, is there some way to launch the phoenix.server allowing more verbosing?

```
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET someurl
** (exit) an exception was raised
** (KeyError) key :response not found in: %{conn_map}... (truncated)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set [the `:truncate` option](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-runtime-configuration) for Logger in your `config/dev.exs`:

```
config :logger, truncate: :infinity
```

**EDIT:** Important note: This isn't something to add to the config :logger, :console, ... line, it should be a new line to itself

Comment: Important note: This isn't something to add to the `config :logger, :console, ...` line, it should be a new line to itself

Comment: @BrianUnderwood can you elaborate why?

Comment: Not perfectly ;)  But I think that `config :logger, :console, ...` is setting the `:console` key under `:logger`, which is separate from setting the `:logger` configuration generally.  Maybe? 

Comment: @BrianUnderwood - Your comment should be part of this answer. It took me way too much time to figure out that missing bit.

Comment: Done  (...SO says I need more characters!)